# DNN Website log

Tags: asp.net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-7

Hello I got a question regarding the website log of DNN.
When I want to create  a report, for example: page views per month, and I generate the results then I get a view something like this:

```
Month   Views   Visitors    Users
6       1138    3           5
```

It works perfectly but what I do not understand is the values for visitors and users? What is the difference between a user and a visitor?

Am I correct to conclude that 8 people in total have watched 1138 pages?

Comment: A user is someone who is logged in to the website (Admin, registered user etc). And your assumptions is correct hat those 8 people have viewed 1138 pages. However I would recommend Google Analytics instead of the Log. Much more detail and statistics.

Comment: The "log" will also start to fill up space on your Database or Filesystem depending on how long you keep the data for, and how high your traffic is.